# Too many elements inserted on push in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, object

So I built this function for a card game, for the "deal card" feature:

```
const dealCards = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let card = cards.pop()
        playerHands[i].hand.push(card)
    }
}
```

The main purpose of it is to insert an object into the

```
hand: []
```

element of playerHands

Player Hands is structured like this:

```
0: {id: 0, user: 'Player 1', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
1: {id: 0.9801915170560507, user: 'Player 2', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
2: {id: 0.0006669572315951555, user: 'Player 3', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
3: {id: 0.5767750038678146, user: 'Player 4', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
4: {id: 0.6448035494497826, user: 'Player 5', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
```

and the element im trying to push into hand like this :

```
{suits: '♦', value: '9'}
```

The issue I'm having is that instead of running through the for loop and inserting a new element for every user ( based on the `[i]` index), it insert this for every user:

```
0: {suits: '♦', value: 'K'}
1: {suits: '♦', value: 'Q'}
2: {suits: '♦', value: 'B'}
3: {suits: '♦', value: '10'}
4: {suits: '♦', value: '9'}
```

Here's an example:

Let's say there are 5 players.

The loop runs 5 times.

It increments `i` like it's supposed to.

But for some reason, instead of having one different card for every user, I get all 5 cards from the pop for every user.

So every user gets the same 5 cards in their hand

Here's an example of what I see in the browser:

[browser sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bgG1.png)

I'm at a loss of why it is doing this, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How **exactly** do you initialize the `.hand` arrays, and in particular are you certain that they're separate arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `users` array, but assuming it has the same length like `playerHands` array then I use the `playerHands` array for iteration.

```js
const dealCards = () => {
    for( let i = 0; i < playerHands.length; i++ ) {
        let card = cards.pop()
        playerHands[i].hand.push(card)
    }
}

let playerHands = [
    {id: 0, user: 'Player 1', hand: Array(0), score: 0},
    {id: 0.9801915170560507, user: 'Player 2', hand: Array(0), score: 0},
    {id: 0.0006669572315951555, user: 'Player 3', hand: Array(0), score: 0},
    {id: 0.5767750038678146, user: 'Player 4', hand: Array(0), score: 0},
    {id: 0.6448035494497826, user: 'Player 5', hand: Array(0), score: 0}
]

let cards = [
    {suits: '♦', value: 'K'},
    {suits: '♦', value: 'Q'},
    {suits: '♦', value: 'B'},
    {suits: '♦', value: '10'},
    {suits: '♦', value: '9'}
]

dealCards()
console.log(playerHands) // to show the result
```